# After upgrade to magento 2.4.6-p3, the pagination is not working

Tags: module, theme, ajax, pagination, ajax-pagination

Upgraded my magento to 2.4.6 from 2.4.0 and the pagination is showing but it is not working. when i am clicking on page 2, it is not going on next page and the url is also not updating. Here is my code for app/design/frontend/new/cloth/Magento_Theme/templates/html/pager.phtml. Please help!

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Pager template
 *
 * @see \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager
 */

?>
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
    
    if(!empty($category)){
      $current_prod_layout = $category->getPageLayout();
    }
    else{
      $current_prod_layout ="default";
    }
$requestInterface = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface');

$routeName      = $requestInterface->getRouteName();
 if($current_prod_layout == "collection" && $routeName == "catalog"){
        ?>
        <?php if ($block->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>

            <?php if ($block->getUseContainer()): ?>
            <div class="pager">
            <?php endif ?>

                <?php if ($block->getShowAmounts()): ?>
                <p class="toolbar-amount">
                    <span class="toolbar-number">
                    <?php if ($block->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Items %1 to %2 of %3 total', $block->getFirstNum(), $block->getLastNum(), $block->getTotalNum()) ?>
                    <?php elseif ($block->getTotalNum() == 1): ?>
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('%1 Item', $block->getTotalNum()) ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('%1 Item(s)', $block->getTotalNum()) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </span>
                </p>
                <?php endif ?>

                <?php if ($block->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
                <div class="pages" style="display:none">
                    <strong class="label pages-label" id="paging-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Page') ?></strong>
                    <ul class="items pages-items" aria-labelledby="paging-label">
                    <?php if (!$block->isFirstPage()): ?>
                        <li class="item pages-item-previous">
                            <?php $text = $block->getAnchorTextForPrevious() ? $block->getAnchorTextForPrevious() : '';?>
                            <a class="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $text ? 'link ' : 'action '?> previous" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPreviousPageUrl() ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $text ? $text : __('Previous') ?>">
                                <span class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Page') ?></span>
                                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $text ? $text : __('Previous') ?></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif;?>

                    <?php if ($block->canShowFirst()): ?>
                        <li class="item">
                            <a class="page first" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFirstPageUrl() ?>">
                                <span class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Page') ?></span>
                                <span>1</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif;?>

                    <?php if ($block->canShowPreviousJump()): ?>
                        <li class="item">
                            <a class="page previous jump" title="" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPreviousJumpUrl() ?>">
                                <span>...</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif;?>

                    <?php foreach ($block->getFramePages() as $_page): ?>
                        <?php if ($block->isPageCurrent($_page)): ?>
                            <li class="item current">
                                <strong class="page">
                                    <span class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('You\'re currently reading page') ?></span>
                                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_page ?></span>
                                </strong>
                            </li>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <li class="item">
                                <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPageUrl($_page) ?>" class="page">
                                    <span class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Page') ?></span>
                                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_page ?></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    <?php endforeach;?>

                    <?php if ($block->canShowNextJump()): ?>
                        <li class="item">
                            <a class="page next jump" title="" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getNextJumpUrl() ?>">
                                <span>...</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif;?>

                    <?php if ($block->canShowLast()): ?>
                      <li class="item">
                          <a class="page last" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLastPageUrl() ?>">
                              <span class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Page') ?></span>
                              <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLastPageNum() ?></span>
                          </a>
                      </li>
                    <?php endif;?>

                    <?php if (!$block->isLastPage()): ?>
                        <li class="item pages-item-next">
                            <?php $text = $block->getAnchorTextForNext() ? $block->getAnchorTextForNext() : '';?>
                            <a class="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $text ? 'link ' : 'action '?> next" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getNextPageUrl() ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $text ? $text : __('Next') ?>">
                                <span class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Page') ?></span>
                                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $text ? $text : __('Next') ?></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif;?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($block->isShowPerPage()): ?>
                <div class="limiter">
                    <strong class="limiter-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Show') ?></strong>
                    <select id="limiter" data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"event":"change"}}' class="limiter-options">
                        <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableLimit() as $_key => $_limit): ?>
                            <option value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"<?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?>
                                selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_limit ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                    <span class="limiter-text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('per page') ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php if ($block->getUseContainer()): ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php
    } else{ ?>
       
<?php if ($block->getCollection()->getSize()): 

?>
    <?php //if ($block->getUseContainer()): ?>
    <div class="pager">
     <?php //endif ?>

        <?php if ($block->getShowAmounts()): ?>
        <p class="toolbar-amount">
            <span class="toolbar-number">
            <?php if ($block->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml(
                    __('Items %1 to %2 of %3 total', $block->getFirstNum(), $block->getLastNum(), $block->getTotalNum())
                ) ?>
            <?php elseif ($block->getTotalNum() == 1): ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('%1 Item', $block->getTotalNum())) ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('%1 Item(s)', $block->getTotalNum())) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </span>
        </p>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if ($block->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
        <div class="pages">
            <strong class="label pages-label" id="paging-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Page')) ?></strong>
            <ul class="items pages-items" aria-labelledby="paging-label">
            <?php if (!$block->isFirstPage()): ?>
                <li class="item pages-item-previous">
                    <?php $text = $block->getAnchorTextForPrevious() ? $block->getAnchorTextForPrevious() : '';?>
                    <a class="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($text ? 'link ' : 'action ') ?> previous"
                       href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPreviousPageUrl()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($text ? $text : __('Previous')) ?>">
                        <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Page')) ?></span>
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($text ? $text : __('Previous')) ?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if ($block->canShowFirst()): ?>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="page first" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFirstPageUrl()) ?>">
                        <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Page')) ?></span>
                        <span>1</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if ($block->canShowPreviousJump()): ?>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="page previous jump"
                       title=""
                       href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPreviousJumpUrl()) ?>">
                        <span>...</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php foreach ($block->getFramePages() as $_page): ?>
                <?php if ($block->isPageCurrent($_page)): ?>
                    <li class="item current">
                        <strong class="page">
                            <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('You\'re currently reading page')) ?></span>
                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_page) ?></span>
                        </strong>
                    </li>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <li class="item">
                        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPageUrl($_page)) ?>" class="page">
                            <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Page')) ?></span>
                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_page) ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php endif;?>
            <?php endforeach;?>

            <?php if ($block->canShowNextJump()): ?>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="page next jump" title="" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getNextJumpUrl()) ?>">
                        <span>...</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if ($block->canShowLast()): ?>
              <li class="item">
                  <a class="page last" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getLastPageUrl()) ?>">
                      <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Page')) ?></span>
                      <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getLastPageNum()) ?></span>
                  </a>
              </li>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if (!$block->isLastPage()): ?>
                <li class="item pages-item-next">
                    <?php $text = $block->getAnchorTextForNext() ? $block->getAnchorTextForNext() : '';?>
                    <a class="<?= /* @noEscape */ $text ? 'link ' : 'action ' ?> next"
                       href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getNextPageUrl()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($text ? $text : __('Next')) ?>">
                        <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Page')) ?></span>
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($text ? $text : __('Next')) ?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($block->isShowPerPage()): ?>
            <div class="limiter">
                <strong class="limiter-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Show')) ?></strong>
                <select id="limiter" data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"event":"change"}}' class="limiter-options">
                    <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableLimit() as $_key => $_limit): ?>
                        <option value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getLimitUrl($_key)) ?>"
                            <?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?>
                            selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_limit) ?>
                        </option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <span class="limiter-text"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('per page')) ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php //if ($block->getUseContainer()): ?>
    </div>
    <?php //endif ?>

<?php endif ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Not sure this is related to this specific file, as there was no major update in this file. Try renaming it to `_pager.phtml` to check if it works with the default file. You added some tags about "ajax", you probably have a third party extension/custom module to manage ajax and which is not compatible anymore with the latest version

Comment: i tried removing the file but still it is not working with default file

Comment: Hi @TishaJhanwar, Instead of removing the file just disable the current active theme. The page layout might can have some conflicts.